# Error: <spyOn> : getApplications() method does not exist Angular jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

I'm trying to mock an service in my Angular unit test, but I get the error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : getApplications() method does not exist Angular unit test
```

I'm using jasmin and spy like this

```
function configureapplicationServiceMock() {
applicationServiceMock = jasmine.createSpy('ApplicationServiceMock');
applicationServiceMock.application$ = Observable.of(Applications.ApplicationDummy);
const applicationInstellingen = new ApplicationInstellingen();
applicationInstellingen.emailEnabled = false;
applicationServiceMock.instellingen = applicationInstellingen;
spyOn(applicationServiceMock, 'getApplications');
}
```

and this function is called in the beforeeach function like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    configureapplicationServiceMock();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FileUploadModule, RouterModule.forRoot([])],
        declarations: [SendComponent, ResourcePipeStub],
        providers: [
            { provide: ResourcePipeStub, useClass: ResourcePipeStub },
            { provide: NotificationService, useFactory: () => notificationServiceMock },
            { provide: ApplicationService, useValue: applicationServiceMock }
        ],
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SendComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

I tryed different things like spyOn with .and.returnValue(), but still not working. I even tryed to do osmething like this applicationServiceMock.getApplications = //function is created, but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?